# Why is my logistic regression fit that bad?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, residuals, diagnostic

I was requested by a professor to analyze a high dimensional dataset (92 cases, 400+ variables, and a lot of NAs...) of various patient outcomes (gaussian distributed, counts, and binary) and their blood clotting tests. He requests confidence intervals over coefficients and a simple model, being no expert in statistics (and I am not either). The main goal is statistical inference, not prediction, and I am using R.

So, after having researched different models for a long time, I came up with the following plan of analysis:

1. **Multiple imputation**: following analyses are done on a pooled long format dataset.
2. [**Bolasso**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mht/mht.pdf): to select predictors for further analysis based on their frequency of selection.
3. **OLS or logistic regression**: using the selected predictors. I proceeded by including predictors in decreasing order of bolasso frequency selection up to the first non significant (p>0.05) predictor.
4. backwards stepwise regression (requested by my professor, less interesting to me as it has been extensively criticized in the literature)

I used *glm.diag.plots()* from [*boot*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf), and *residualPlots()* and *influenceIndexPlot()* from [*car*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/car.pdf). I already removed 4 influential observations that had a high Cook's distance, as explained [in this book chapter](https://us.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/upm-binaries/38503_Chapter6.pdf), but to no avail.

**Why are the green fits in my *residualPlots()* totally off? Can I do anything about it?**

## Model (outcome = bleeder y/n)

```
Call:
glm(formula = as.formula(paste(outcome, "~", paste(names(Q$bootstrapped.lasso$summary[signif.preds]), 
    sep = "", collapse = "+"), sep = "")), family = "binomial", 
    data = d)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.9947  -0.6291  -0.4362  -0.1706   2.5597  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -1.57642    1.19482  -1.319 0.187044    
EXTEM.alpha.1   0.04667    0.01185   3.937 8.25e-05 ***
EXTEM.CA.15.1  -0.12734    0.01562  -8.152 3.59e-16 ***
FIBTEM.alpha.1  0.05031    0.01372   3.668 0.000244 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 482.26  on 455  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 379.06  on 452  degrees of freedom
AIC: 387.06

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

## Pairs

[image: scatterplot matrix]

## glm.diag.plots()

[image: diagnostics plots]

## residualPlots()

[image: diagnostics plots]

## influenceIndexPlot()

[image: diagnostics plots]

Comment: Almost 7 years has passed since the question was asked so I hope the objective of satisfying the professor was achieved.  Otherwise there appears to be no specific medical objective other than to take a look at the data.  Without a specific objective I can only suggest that you remove bleeder from your "pairs" figure but add it back in as two different symbols (or colors) for the other 3 variables.

Comment: No, I got a severe admonition for not completing the requested objective of spinning a clinically & statistically significant result from this data in the form of "Look at all the stuff I found with my 400 back-to-back t-tests! You're a loser!". 7y later, I now hold a degree in epidemiology and am currently in the process of solving this (and all the other BS similar requests over the years), as the professor in question will leave for retirement at the end of the week.